# System.NullReferenceException on this.Controls.Add() with winforms and C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

I have developed a small WinForm application with C#. 
I have released this app for years, and a lot of users use it on many different Windows system, Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8,  32bit and 64bit.

But a few days ago one user reported a crash when launching application on a Windows 7 64bit machine. Because I can't reproduce the error on my side so I sent him the debug version which can output log information.

Now I have located the line which fails on

```
this.Controls.Add(this.myUserControl);
```

It's a line which Visual Studio generated from the Forms Designer.  "this.myUserControl" is an instance of an User Control.  This User Control is built in this project, and not includes any external components.  Just built with some standard UI controls. 
The .NET error information is

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

I have added code to test whether the this.myUserControl is null before adding it to controls, it's definitely not null.

I have tried a lot of methods,  like using corflags.exe to force it running in 32bit mode or changing the build target framework to 3.5 (before it's 2.0)

Nothing changes.  It always crashes on that line.

I have tested this app on Windows 7 64bit before I released it, and this app have a lot of users using it on Windows 7 64bit. So I think I should not change any code. But I don't have any direction on how to solve this problem.

Should I tell the user to reinstall Windows or repair .Net Framework?  Did anyone meet this error on Windows 7 64bit?

English is not my native language so sorry for my English.

---

The code related to the user control, all these codes is generated from the Forms Designer:

```
private MyUserControl myUserControl;

this.myUserControl = new ProjectNameSpace.MyUserControl();
this.myUserControl.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.myUserControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 80);
this.myUserControl.Name = "myUserControl";
this.myUserControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(775, 412);
this.myUserControl.TabIndex = 2;
this.myUserControl.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.myUserControl_Resize);

this.Controls.Add(this.myUserControl);
```

Comment: Well can you show code of how you create the instance of the UserControl..? please show the code that you are using..? make sure you are not trying to reference the control out of scope. show where you are creating the instance of the `UserControl` also this.Controls what does it refer to `Panel, ListView, etc..`

Comment: The User Control has Panel , DataGridView and another UserControl which is also built in this project and does't have any external components.   And the codes in this UserControl's Designer.cs is too long. I am afraid I can't paste it here.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you positive that is the crashing line? I am wondering if somehow the symbols/source didn't match up exactly right.. And if it is for sure that line - does it happen somewhere in the `Add()` method (.Net code), or on that actual line? (your code)

Comment: Why break your head when that dude can simply try reinstalling .Net Framework? My guess is that something is messed up in there. If that doesn't work - break away.

Comment: I hide the UserControl's real name and the project's real name.  I just replace them with "myUserControl" and "ProjectNameSpace".  Because of some rules in my company.

Comment: @canhazbits  I am sure that line is the crashing line.  for now it only happends on this actual line.  The form can add() other controls correctly.

Comment: I have found this after some search on web.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135   Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool.    I will send this to the user to see what happends.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, `this.myUserControl` is not null; so `this.Controls` might be the issue. Check for `System.ComponentModel.IContainer components` and `InitializeComponent()`; there possibly be something lack or not initialized.

Override `OnLayout` or `OnPaint` would be helpful for debugging, `IsHandleCreated` could also be a key point for figuring out something abnormal.

The simplest way would be create a new user control with designer, and paste the code you've written for the business. Remember to name the controls as same as the original.

Comment: @user2351537: You're welcome. Maybe you can provide the full code with external site like github, and that would be helpful to figure out what is the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

As for the stack/line of the crash; so you are saying this line in question in your Designer code is at the very top of the stack, even if you have "Show External Code" checked?

Although you have confirmed it is crashing on the line in question:

`this.Controls.Add(this.myUserControl);`

I am a bit suspicious. If it is crashing on *that* line, and not *inside* of the Controls.Add method, then it seems like there are only two possibilities:

1) this.Controls is null - have any controls been added before this one? If so, it seems impossible.

2) `this` is null - which is impossible..

One thing you could try is sending this customer code that is just a simple for, adding a simple control (that is not your custom control). Or have them run some other C# forms app. That may help you narrow things down.